# GitLab CI: How to disable commit/auto pipeline for other branches than master?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I GitLab every change to a branch triggers the pipeline to run. I actually don't want that to happen for every branch but only my main branch.

BUT I still want to be able to trigger the pipeline for other branches manually. So using the

```
only
  - master
```

is not the whole game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
only
 - master
 - web // if you want to trigger from the web interface
 - triggers // if you want to trigger by invoking by using a trigger token
```

Comment: I will ad merge_requests to the list